# WebWorks Viewport Width Issues

Tags: css, webkit, viewport, blackberry-webworks

On the Blackberry Bold 9900 running 7.1 Bundle 998 (v7.1.0.284, Platform 5.1.0.230) I am having a strange viewport related issue.

I am non-deterministically seeing `screen.width` alternate between `320px` and `356px`.

This affects the behavior of rendered content because I have a

```
<body>
   <div style="width:100%">
   </div>
</body>
```

that approx 50% of the time renders correctly (i.e. no horizontal scroll), but the rest of the time renders zoomed in and scrolls horizontally by 36px.  Setting a fixed width on the body i.e. `320px` causes the zoom issue to be resolved, but still has a white scrollable area on the right side.

Viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`

Comment: Are you accounting for margins/padding/borders on the div or body element?

Comment: Yes and I even went as far as to set a 0px margin on both div and body with no effect.

Comment: Can you show a copy of the viewport you are using on the page?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is an issue with this device where `width:100%` causes the content to render wider than the screen.  The fix is to set `width:auto`.